# не получается масштабировать изображение под разные экраны

Tags: android, изображения

в папке `assets` лежит изображения, под обычные телефоны изображение норм, пробую адаптировать под планшеты и большие экраны, создал layout(large,xlarge), проставил размеры изображения, однако возникла проблема: если я ставлю у контейнера параметры wrap_content, то на маленьких экранах все ок, на больших оно мелкое, однако если ставлю match_parent ширину и высоту `350dp,550dp`, то изображение растягивается по контейнеру, и становится как будто расплюченным... с параметром scaleType игрался, оно не играет влияния если параметры выставлены из последнего варианта.подскажите как быть? фото прилагаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылки на изображения лежат в json файле в assets, загружаю так:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(EXTRA_STATE_KEY))
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt(EXTRA_STATE_KEY);
    mItem = (String) getArguments().
            getSerializable(EXTRA_ITEM);
    LoadMediaTask loadMediaTask = new LoadMediaTask();
    loadMediaTask.execute(mItem);
    try {
        mSubject = loadMediaTask.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(EXTRA_STATE_KEY, position);
}

class LoadMediaTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Subject> {

    @Override
    protected Subject doInBackground(String... params) {
        mgr = getActivity().getAssets();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream;
            inputStream = mgr.open(mItem);
            mSubject = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Subject.class);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mSubject;
    }
}
```

потом метод парсит ссылки:

```
    public void OnChangePhoto() {
    mp.reset();
    mgr = getActivity().getAssets();
    if (mSubject.content != null) {
        try {
            Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(mSubject.content.get(position).photos);
            iteration_Change_Question(imgUri,mImageSwitcher);

            String mName = mSubject.content.get(position).signature;
            tv.setText(mName);

            Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(mSubject.content.get(position).sounds);
            String sound2 = soundUri.getPath().substring("/android_asset/".length());

            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd(sound2);
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            afd.close();
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

и еще метод :

```
 public void iteration_Change_Question(Uri imgUri, ImageSwitcher view) {
    String stream = imgUri.getPath().substring("/android_asset/".length());
    String add = "assets://" + stream;
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(add, new CustomViewAware(view));
}
```

еще класс

```
  public class CustomViewAware extends ViewAware {
    public CustomViewAware(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setImageDrawableInto(Drawable drawable, View view) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setImageBitmapInto(Bitmap bitmap, View view) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
    }
}
```

попробовал делать так:

```
 @Override
protected void setImageBitmapInto(Bitmap bitmap, View view) {
    bitmap.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM);
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
}
```

и так :

```
        @Override
    protected void setImageBitmapInto(Bitmap bitmap, View view) {
        bitmap.setDensity(context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
    }
}
```

но не помогает((

Comment: Как вы их из assets загружаете? Добавьте пример.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja добавил код на ваш комментарий..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема, что если изображение грузится не из ресурсов, то после загрузки надо выставить правильное значение `density` для него.

```
Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
// custom density
bmp.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXX);
// or display density
bmp.setDensity(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
```

Посмотрите в этом направлении.
Может проще положить все в ресурсы?

Comment: да я тоже склоняюсь чтоб все хранить в ресурсах, просто в assets удобно.. не подскажите, в каком моменте кода мне необходимо проводить данную операцию? у меня получается что путь к фото применяется только в  ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(add, new CustomViewAware(view));
или можно как то обработать данные прямо в кастомном ViewAware?

Comment: Я не пользыюсь этими библиотеками, точно не скажу, но должен быть где-то колбэк, что все загружено, там и меняйте.